# View route structure of Flask app

Tags: python, flask

Is there a way to see the routes each page makes in the application. Like sort of a sitemap to see if there are unnecessary pages who do nothing or got useless because of the growth of the application. Or another way to see the structure of my site?

```
         -----------------------
        |                       |
login--home--about              |
      |                         |
      -- contact--contact form--|
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do precisely what you want, but maybe that's a starting point. This Flask snippet lists the app's routes. http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/117/

> ```
> from flask_script import Manager
> from myapp import app
> from flask import url_for
> manager = Manager(app)
>
> @manager.command
> def list_routes():
>     import urllib
>     output = []
>     for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
>
>         options = {}
>         for arg in rule.arguments:
>             options[arg] = "[{0}]".format(arg)
>
>         methods = ','.join(rule.methods)
>         url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **options)
>         line = urllib.parse.unquote("{:50s} {:20s} {}".format(rule.endpoint, methods, url))
>         output.append(line)
>
>     for line in sorted(output):
>         print line
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     manager.run()
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Flask comes with the `routes` command to list the routes registered with the application.

```
$ export FLASK_APP=my_app
$ flask routes
    Endpoint                             Methods    Rule
-----------------------------------  ---------  ----------------------------------------------
auth.login                           GET, POST  /auth/login
auth.logout                          GET        /auth/logout
auth.register                        GET, POST  /auth/register
index                                GET        /
```